# Increasing Kryo logging level

Tags: corda

We've encountered a problem with RPC and want to increase the logging level of Kryo to be able to investigate. The [Kryo docs](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#logging) suggest running `Log.TRACE()`, but we can't find anywhere to do this within Corda.

Is there any way in Corda, or in our CorDapp to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Log4j to configure logging, as we do in the template CorDapps (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V2/config/dev/log4j2.xml), you just need to change the logging level in the log4j2.xml file.

Change:

```
<Configuration status="info">
```

To:

```
<Configuration status="trace">
```

Comment: This didn't work I'm afraid. :-(

Looks like Kryo doesn't support log4j2.xml out of the box, Corda would need to write an adapter for this to work.